# reading a CSV from S3 and maintaining datatypes in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, types

I'm reading a csv file from S3, when the list gets created it is single quoting everything as a string.

This is the python code I'm using to create the list:

```
s3_clientobj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=S3_BUCKET, Key=mkey)  

for line in s3_clientobj['Body'].iter_lines():
    td.append(line.decode('utf-8').split(','))
```

Here's what the list looks like:

```
[['I', '13', '', 'mynull'], ['I', '14', '', 'mynull'], ['I', '15', '', 'mynull'], ['I', '16', '', 'mynull']]
```

I may have different sized files with different columns.  How do I not quote the empty strings and numbers? I'm inserting this into a postgres database in the end, and the empty string should be treated as nulls...but the execute_many treats both the numbers and empty string as a string.

Thanks for any help!

I'm editing the first post..comments looked un-aligned...

So I switched to using Data Wrangler in the lambda function on AWS.  But it seems to mess up the first row when reading the csv into a dataframe:

```
print(td)
           
I  13  Unnamed: 2  mynull
0  I  14         NaN  mynull
1  I  15         NaN  mynull
2  I  16         NaN  mynull

 tuples = [tuple(x) for x in td.to_numpy()]
 print(tuples)

[('I', 14, nan, 'mynull'), ('I', 15, nan, 'mynull'), ('I', 16, nan, 'mynull')]
```

Comment: There are no datatypes in CSV files, everything is a string. Libraries like pandas will automatically convert columns to numbers when all the values are numeric. If you're not using that, you'll need to do the conversion in your own code.

Comment: And be very careful with automatic conversion of types.  There's an [entire class of erorrs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.09785) this can cause, some of them pretty catastrophic.

Comment: @AnonCoward my favorite is the genes that had to be renamed because Excel kept screwing them up.

Comment: Ugh...just head to tell it there's no header.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If so, feel free to add your own Answer.